# Why would PHP's stat throw a RuntimeException?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, php-vcr

Is there a reason why a call to `stat` would throw a `RuntimeException`? This is during testing with phpunit, using CakePHP and PHP-VCR. The call to stat includes the [error control operator, @](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). So it's:

The error occurs in the PHP-VCR code (StreamProcessor.php line 291).

```
    try {
        $result = @stat($path);
    } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
        error_log(print_r($e, true));
    }


'type' => (int) 2,
'message' => 'stat(): stat failed for /x/y/z/mycakephpprojet/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_cake_eng',
'file' => '/x/y/z/mycakephpprojet/app/Vendor/php-vcr/php-vcr/src/VCR/Util/StreamProcessor.php',
'line' => (int) 291
```

What I know is that the referenced file is missing (it's a cache file that is generated at some point later). So I'd expect stat to return false, not throw an exception.

Notes:

- I was thinking perhaps it's thrown by some custom handler of a composer package (like phpunit). However, `error_reporting()` reports 24575, where I'd expect it to be 0 because of the @ error control operator. Also, I looked through all the `set_error_handler` calls and even put debug calls in those and I'm sure it's not from them.
- The stack trace from the exception object has the most recent line as

  ```
  '#0 [internal function]: VCR\Util\StreamProcessor->url_stat('/home/tylercoll...', 2)
  ```

  so I don't feel like there's another level that I could possibly intercept to inspect.
- Oddly, the RuntimeException that's thrown cannot be handled with my own custom `set_exception_handler`. But if I manually use `throw new \RuntimeException`, my custom handler will be used.
- ONE time the exception type was `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`. I'm 99% positive that I ran it again immediately and it's been RuntimeException since then. But the warning would make sense given that the error's type is reported as 2 (aka E_WARNING).
- One of the reasons I think it's something to do with PHP is because if I remove the @ error control operator, I get many WARNINGs (not exceptions) saying stat failed. However, this I'm pretty sure is from the CakePHP test harness because after many of those go by, then I see `PHPUnit 3.7.37 by Sebastian Bergmann. Configuration read from phpunit.xml`. And then the failure is after that.
- I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.4.23.

Comment: The global value of error_reporting is independent from the `@` operator. `@` simply supresses the output any errors of the function it has been attached to. (and is considered bad practice nowadays, anyway.)

Comment: Could you please try the following: 1. Remove the `@`. 2. Catch all `\Exception`s. In the `catch` block, dump the exception class (`var_dump(get_class($e))`). It might be that at the time of the error, the exception is of a different type, and gets converted to `\RuntimeException` later.

Comment: @lxg, the code where this happens is in the PHP-VCR library. I'm not at liberty to change everything, although I did fork a version ([see changes](https://github.com/tylercollier/php-vcr/commit/358f52182861bd92996f3aa58349e367897f060c)). According to [the docs I linked in the question](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), `@` makes `error_reporting()` report 0. And when I do `var_dump(get_class($e))`, it's \RuntimeException (no namespace).

Comment: Sorry. For 1), if I remove the @, there is no change, except that I see a number of warnings for many missing files that stat fails on. Those are for the calls I believe from CakePHP's test harness before PHPUnit starts the unit test. I will make a note of that in my question.

Comment: I'd never recommend to alter 3rd party libs permanently, but for debugging, you might temporarily sneak in a `print_r()`. ;) Maybe it would help to modify the catch block of PHP-VCR's error handler and dump the call stack (`print_r($e->getTraceAsString())`).

Comment: I forked the PHP-VCR repo to create my fix and linked it in an above comment. I also mention the stack trace in the question.